# Strange warning using dask.dataframe to read csv

Tags: python, warnings, pytest, dask, future-warning

I am using dask dataframe module to read a csv.

```
In [3]: from dask import dataframe as dd                                                                               

In [4]: dd.read_csv("/file.csv", sep=",", dtype=str, encoding="utf-8", error_bad_lines=False, collection=True, blocksize=64e6)
```

I used to this with no problem, but today a strange warning showed up:

```
   FutureWarning: The default value of auto_mkdir=True has been deprecated and will be changed to auto_mkdir=False by default in a future release.
      FutureWarning,
```

This didn't worried me until I realised it breaks my unit tests, because, when using this from console, it's simple a warning, but the tests set for my app have broken because of this.

Does anyone know the cause of this warning or how to get rid of it?

Comment: Have you updated your dask version recently? Or are you using an online jupyter notebook?

Comment: Wild guess, but what happens if you set auto_mkdir=True in your read_csv function?

Comment: @d_kennetz I'm using dask 2.12, latest release, haven't change it

Comment: @boomkin already tried that, but raises an error: auto_mkdir is not a valid kwarg for read_csv

Comment: I have temporarily fixed this by setting:
filterwarnings =
    error
    ignore::FutureWarning

in my pytest.ini, but still I have the feeling that this warning shouldn't be happening

Comment: Looks like Dask changed that `auto_mkdir` behavior a couple months ago: https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/5526

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-answering for documentation:

- This [issue](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/6028) appears in fsspec==0.6.3 and dask==2.12.0 and will be removed in the future.
- To prevent pytest failing because of the warning, add or edit a `pytest.ini` file in your project and set

```
filterwarnings =
    error
    ignore::UserWarning
```

- If you want dask to silent the warning at all, explicit set this in the function call `storage_options=dict("auto_mkdir"=True)`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same thing. Finding no answers as to what might have replaced the feature, I decided to see if the feature is even needed any more. Sure enough,  as of Pandas 1.3.0 the warnings that previously motivated the feature no longer appear. So

```
pd.read_csv(import_path, error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False, names=cols)
```

simply became

```
pd.read_csv(import_path, names=cols)
```

and works fine with no errors or warnings.